# How to keep the number fraction format in Python3.x while performing simple operations?

Tags: python

In code, I would like to keep the format of number while doing different simple operations (e.g. multiplication  1/6 * 1/6 ) in python 3.x.

I want to have:

```
{
    2: 1/36,
    3: 2/36,
    4: 3/36,
    5: 4/36,
    6: 5/36,
    7: 6/36,
    8: 5/36,
    9: 4/36,
    10: 3/36,
    11: 2/36,
    12: 1/36
}
```

but i get this:

```
{
    2: 0.027777777777777776,
    3: 0.05555555555555555,
    4: 0.08333333333333333,
    5: 0.1111111111111111,
    6: 0.1388888888888889,
    7: 0.16666666666666669,
    8: 0.1388888888888889,
    9: 0.1111111111111111,
    10: 0.08333333333333333,
    11: 0.05555555555555555,
    12: 0.027777777777777776
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any programming language **not** evaluating the expression to a float without mentioning.

In case of python you should use module [fraction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html?highlight=fraction#module-fractions).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module and string formatting you can print rational numbers like this

```
import fractions
print("{}".format(fractions.Fraction(0.027777777777777776).limit_denominator()))
```

this will output

```
1/36
```

Comment: Welcome, if this answer is helpful and solves your problem you might consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) it as answer. :-)